# Oneline bash command to dump and create PostgreSQL db

Tags: database, postgresql, psql

Sometimes I need to create a database called `DB_DEV` which is the exact copy (same scheme and data) as already existing `DB`. Id `DB_DEV` already exists, I want just to drop it and recreate it.

I used this command:

```
"pg_dump --clean -U user db | psql db_dev"
```

which seemed to work but I realised that it doesn't deletes tables which aren't present in `db`.

So if I run this command and then create a table `"table"` in `DEV_DB` and run the command again, the `"table"` is still present in `DEV_DB` database although in `DB` isn't.

Do you know how to modify the command to make it work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You could drop and recreate the database before restoring the dump:

```
psql postgres -c 'drop database db_dev; create database db_dev;'
pg_dump --clean -U user db | psql db_dev
```

Or:

```
dropdb db_dev
createdb db_dev
pg_dump --clean -U user db | psql db_dev
```